# Which mechanism is used to trigger a call from jsp to servlets using href

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I'm using href to call servlet URL and it's working fine. 
I want add parameters and get response from this request. Is it possible? 
I tried with AJAX call but CORS issue found(when call external Api).

Is any better way is there..?

Example :
`<a href="servleturl">click</a>`

Comment: You can not enable CORS in standard updated web browser. No way around.

Comment: Is any alternative way call external api from jsp with out this CORS issue.

Comment: maybe get the servlet to call the external api

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try like this:

    <a href="servleturl?name=<%=userName%>&country=<%=userCountry%>">click</a>

    In Servlet:

    String userName= request.getParameter("name");
    String userCountry= request.getParameter("country");

OR If you are using JSTL:

<c:url value="/servleturl" var="url">
  <c:param name="name" value="userName" />
  <c:param name="country" value="userCountry" />
</c:url>

<a href="<c:out value='${url}'/>">ServletLink</a>


For enabling CORS create a filter having overrided method like this:
// content of Request Filter
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
                throws IOException, ServletException {

            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) request;    

            ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, OPTIONS, HEAD, PUT, POST");

            HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

            if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
                resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
                return;
            }    

            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
```